# Thunar shows me icons from Wine, but I don't have Wine installed. How can I make it forget about Wine?

Tags: icons, wine, xfce, xubuntu, thunar

I've tried the many methods from [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1017186/824054) and therefore I'm confident that I no longer have Wine installed on my Xubuntu 20.04 machine. However, the default icon for opening .dll and similar Windows files in Thunar is clearly from Wine. How can I correct this? I could choose a new default program, but for obvious reasons I don't have a fitting choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunar is just a file manager - I have it here in my Kali machine. Thunar is not part of Wine so far as I know. In any event it is just a file manager.

If you have followed all the steps in the Ask Ubuntu article you referred to, then just delete the icons you do not want. There will not be any impact if Wine was completely removed.

Comment: Apparently I've purged Wine before. I'm surprised that didn't delete the icons. Is there a particular file I should be looking in?

Comment: See if the icon opens anything or is just an empty icon. No harm in deleting that.

Comment: Trying to open the program opens an Open With box.

Comment: Then just delete the icon in Thunar because it is not pointing to anything

Comment: Looks like they were in ~/.local/share/icons